# DynamoDBMapper batch delete with DynamoDBMapperConfig

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I need to batch delete items from a table. For this purpose I wanted to use `dynamoDBMapper.batchDelete(itemsToRemove)`,
but batchDelete method does not accept `DynamoDBMapperConfig` as the last method argument, meanwhile a lot of DynamoDBMapper methods accept it (e.g. `load(), save(), delete(), batchWrite(), batchLoad()`).

I use `DynamoDBMapperConfig` to override table name that was defined with `@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "...")` (as in my case it changes on different profiles):

```
dynamoDBMapperConfig = new DynamoDBMapperConfig.TableNameOverride(tableName).config();
```

I decided to use `batchWrite(objectsToWrite, objectsToDelete, dynamoDBMapperConfig)` for a batch delete items because  batchWrite method accepts dynamoDBMapperConfig argument:

```
dynamoDBMapper.batchWrite(Collections.emptyList(), itemsToRemove, dynamoDBMapperConfig);
```

seems it works fine.

Are there any reasons why batchDelete and batchSave methods don't have DynamoDBMapperConfig as method argument, meanwhile batchWrite has it?
(maybe due to poor design of existing method: `batchDelete(Object... objectsToDelete)`). Are there any pitfalls of using `dynamoDBMapper.batchWrite` with dynamoDBMapperConfig argument?

I use aws sdk version 1.11.217.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `batchWrite` and can pass items to delete in second argument:

```
mapper.batchWrite(Collections.EMPTY_LIST, **objectsToDelete**, dynamoDBMapperConfig);
```

Comment: I know it, but question from another point of view (`Are there any reasons why batchDelete and batchSave methods don't have DynamoDBMapperConfig as method argument`)